# how to update two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i would like to update the information of the of my street address , postal code and city from 2 table 
the 2 table contain its own attribute but they have the same information of street address , postal code and city , now i would like to update the information of the 2 table ... how do i write the update statement ?? anyone can he lp >?? ..

it give me error when i do the update..anyone can check for me ?

```
 UPDATE DEPARTMENT a  INNER JOIN LOCATION b 
  ON a.street address = b.street address
 AND a.postal_code = b.postal_code,
 AND a.city=b.city,
 AND a.country_name = b.county_name,
 SET street_address = 'subang 1 ,subang jaya ' ,
  postal code = '31546',
 city = 'PETALING JAYA ',
  country_name = 'MALAYSIA',
 WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'Accounting';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Comma after `= b.street address`

and reference the columns that should be updated by writing the table alias in front of it. if you want to update fields with the same name in both tables you have to write it out for each column

Comment: i removed it , but it give me error..syntax error near set street address there..

Comment: i also put on a.postal,city , country name = b already ..i still get error

Comment: sry, i overlooked something. you only need the set command one time at the beginning.

Comment: what does that mean ?? i cannot have more than 1 set ?

Comment: i have edit my code ... can u help me check what wrong with it ?

Comment: remove the comma here : `country_name = 'MALAYSIA',`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT a
INNER JOIN LOCATION b ON a.street address = b.street address
AND a.postal_code = b.postal_code
AND a.city=b.city
AND a.country_name = b.county_name
SET a.street_address = 'subang 1 ,subang jaya ',
    b.street_address = 'subang 1 ,subang jaya ',
    a.postal_code = '31546',
    b.postal_code = '31546',
    a.city = 'PETALING JAYA ',
    b.city = 'PETALING JAYA ',
    a.country_name = 'MALAYSIA',
    b.country_name = 'MALAYSIA',
WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'Accounting';
```

Comment: its say my near SET a.street_address = 'subang 1 ,subang jaya ', got syntax error :(